# Lagged values multiple columns with function in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, lag

I would like to create lagged values for multiple columns in R.

First, I used a function to create lead/lag like this:

```
mleadlag <- function(x, n, ts_id) {
        pos <- match(as.numeric(ts_id) + n, as.numeric(ts_id))
        x[pos]
}
```

Second, I would like to apply this function for several columns in R. firm.characteristics is list of columns I would like to compute lagged values.

```
library(dplyr)

firm.characteristics <- colnames(df)[4:6]
for(i in 1:length(firm.characteristics)){
       df <- df %>%
                group_by(company) %>%
                mutate(!!paste0("lag_", i) := mleadlag(df[[i]] ,-1, fye)) %>%
                ungroup()
}
```

However, I didn't get the correct values. The output for all companies in year t is the last row in year t-1. It didn't group by the company any compute the lagged values.

Can anyone help me which is wrong in the loop? Or what should I do to get the correct lagged values?

Thank you so much for your help.

Reproducible sample could be like this:

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(company=1:n, 
                  fye=2009,
                  x=rnorm(n),
                  y=rnorm(n),
                  z=rnorm(n),
                  k=rnorm(n),
                  m=rnorm(n))
dat2 <- data.frame(company=1:n, 
                   fye=2010,
                   x=rnorm(n),
                   y=rnorm(n),
                   z=rnorm(n),
                   k=rnorm(n),
                   m=rnorm(n))
dat3 <- data.frame(company=1:n, 
                   fye=2011,
                   x=rnorm(n),
                   y=rnorm(n),
                   z=rnorm(n),
                   k=rnorm(n),
                   m=rnorm(n))
df <- rbind(dat,dat2,dat3)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Without data it’s hard to look into this. If you are open to other approaches, I have a package on GitHub which might be of help: [{dplyover}](https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/). The first two examples in the readme should cover this case.

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry for that. I added the small sample in the question. Hope that it would be easier to see

Answer (score 1):

I would try to stay away from loops in the tidyverse. Many of the tidyverse applications that would traditionally require loops already exist and are very fast, which creates more efficient and intuitive code (the latter being my opinion). This is a great use case for dplyr's `across()` functionality. I first changed the `df` to a `tibble`.

```
df %>% 
 as_tibble() %>%
 group_by(company) %>% 
 mutate(
   across(firm.characteristics, ~lag(., 1L))
 ) %>% 
 ungroup()
```

This generates the required lagged values. For more information see dplyr's across documentation.

Comment: Hi Griff, Thank you for your response. I just have a quick question, imagine that in our df, we have some companies with non-continuous year. So, by doing like this, they can put NA value for lagged variable of the non-continuous year.

Comment: Could you provide some example data? Cheers.